# twitter bootstrap html tool-tip oddness

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add html tool-tips to an existing page that's made of a table on one side of the page and something else on the other. I want to add the tool-tip to each td in the table.

With the tool-tip added to each td every time I hover over a td the whole table shifts over one cell!

Also, tried only on chrome.

before the hover
[image]

And when I hover over the first td
[image]

Below is a cut down, but fully working example of the oddness, any thoughts appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="static/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="table-responsive" id="23">
                        <TABLE class="table table-bordered table-nonfluid">
                            <tr id="hdr" class="bg-primary h5">
                                <th class="text-center">Mon 18 May</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Thu 21 May</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="day" class="text-center">
                                <td class="bg-danger" 
                                    data-trigger="hover" 
                                    data-placement="auto" 
                                    data-html="true" 
                                    data-title="<div>WHAT!</div>"
                                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                                    >
                                    <sup>300</sup>/<sub>312</sub>
                                </td>
                                <td class="bg-danger"
                                    data-trigger="hover" 
                                    data-placement="auto" 
                                    data-html="true" 
                                    data-title="<div>WHAT!</div>"
                                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                                 >
                                 <sup>277</sup>/<sub>312</sub></td>
                            </tr>
                        </TABLE>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 " style="padding-top: 16px;">
                    <blockquote id="comment_txt">before, after and then on</blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to wrap the content of your td inside a span like this

```
 <td><span data-trigger="hover" style="display:block"
                                data-placement="auto" 
                                data-html="true" 
                                data-title="<div>WHAT!</div>"
                                data-toggle="tooltip"><sup>300</sup>/<sub>312</sub></span></td>
```

Is never a good idea using the tooltips directly on a table element.

Comment: hey if that fixes i don't care if its wrapped in bacon! if it works then its good for me - many thanks

Comment: actually that doesn't fix it it now just pushes the whole table "down" causes a scrollbar to appear

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with this? because i dont see the scrollbar in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a weird issue actually. Never realised it until now. This might not be the perfect fix but a **temporary fix** will be to place a `span` around the text in the `td` for the one on the left and for the `td` on the right leave it as it is right now because it works fine only the left one causes this issue.

### [Bootply Link right here](http://www.bootply.com/gB2U2NucjZ)

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="table-responsive" id="23">
                        <TABLE class="table table-bordered table-nonfluid">
                            <tr id="hdr" class="bg-primary h5">
                                <th class="text-center">Mon 18 May</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Thu 21 May</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="day" class="text-center">
                                <td class="bg-danger" >
                                  <span data-trigger="hover" 
                                    data-placement="auto" 
                                    data-html="true" 
                                    data-title="WHAT!"
                                    data-toggle="tooltip">
                                    <sup>300</sup>/<sub>312</sub>
                                      </span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="bg-danger"
                                    data-trigger="hover" 
                                    data-placement="auto" 
                                    data-html="true" 
                                    data-title="<div>WHAT!</div>"
                                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                                 >
                                 <sup>277</sup>/<sub>312</sub></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="day" class="text-center">
                                <td class="bg-danger" >
                                  <span data-trigger="hover" 
                                    data-placement="auto" 
                                    data-html="true" 
                                    data-title="WHAT!"
                                    data-toggle="tooltip">
                                    <sup>300</sup>/<sub>312</sub>
                                      </span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="bg-danger"
                                    data-trigger="hover" 
                                    data-placement="auto" 
                                    data-html="true" 
                                    data-title="<div>WHAT!</div>"
                                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                                 >
                                 <sup>277</sup>/<sub>312</sub></td>
                            </tr>
                        </TABLE>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 " style="padding-top: 16px;">
                    <blockquote id="comment_txt">before, after and then on</blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem with my fix is simple. The `tooltip` will only show on the left `td` if you hover on the text in the `cell` not on the `table-cell` itself whilst the `tooltip` will show if you hover on the `table cell` on the right. bad for user experience I know but this is as i said a temporary fix.

Comment: I'm curently thinking I should use the data-selector attribute but i'm not sure how - its seems to me and this is just a guess that I need to "anchor" the tooltip to something else.